# google colab Your session crashed for an unknown reason .convert()

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()  

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

I am trying to convert keras to tflite model. But in Google colab When I try to run this code,  I get an error "your session crashed for an unknown reason" at this line "tflite_model = converter.convert() "

I upgrade tensorflow, tfgpu . I tried everything but it didnt work.

Comment: If the error message is too long, the session can be broken. Please try the recent TF version, for example, tf 2.5.0 or tf-nightly. If you can run it on your machine, there is possibility that you can find the actual error message instead of the session crashing without any messages.

Comment: I didn't see any issue in your conversion code.Did you tried with `TF 2.5` or `tf-nightly` as suggested above?